# Поиск валидного ключа ПО

Tags: c#, c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, дали задание найти валидный ключ программы и экзешник (*.exe), какими способами это можно сделать?

Comment: дезассемблировать, понять алгоритм проверки ключа и дальше по обстоятельствам.

Comment: рекомендую IDA PRO для этих целей, желательно бы полную версию)

Comment: Интересное задание, а по какому курсы вы его получили?

Comment: Если речь именно о .net, IDA не особо поможет, а вот dotPeek - в самый раз.

Comment: @Fynivx , в том то и дело что я не знаю, речь идёт о .net или нет

Comment: @Unick , это не курсы